# Adjusting Points with Offset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, editing

I have a collection of GPS points that were collected along a road over the course of a few years.

Some years are right where they are suppose to be, but others are offset by 500 feet. Another year's data is offset by 700 feet.

Is there a way using ArcGIS Pro to adjust these points back onto the road without manually dragging them or snapping it directly along the centerline?

I would like to preserve the relative position of those points in relation to each other after they are moved.

Comment: I think this would be straightforward using ArcPy.  Assuming you have year and XY offset values for those years, where is that data stored?  If you start writing some code and get stuck then present it here and someone here should be able to help.

Comment: I would also add you say "... adjust these points back onto the road without manually dragging them or snapping it directly along the centerline?" If you are not snapping them to the centreline then what is your "adjust points back onto the road"? What you say makes no sense and contradictory.